# SalesForce response to recent CPU Vulnerabilities

Tags: security

Has anyone seen a response from SalesForce yet around the recent "Meltdown, Spectre".

> The severe design flaw in Intel microprocessors that allows sensitive data, such as passwords and crypto-keys, to be stolen from memory is real – and its details have been revealed.

[Media Source](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/01/04/intel_amd_arm_cpu_vulnerability/)

I know this has only just been published in the last few hours, but Microsoft, Amazon and Google have all released responses and have not seen anything from SalesForce yet.

Comment: Take some comfort from the reality that _both_ the vulnerability and code that exploits the vulnerability need to be present for there to be a problem. At least in the core platform, an executable that directly manipulates memory (to exploit the vulnerability) can't be added AFAIK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A colleague forwarded this [Knowledge Article 000269171](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Spectre-and-Meltdown-Vulnerabilities&language=en_US&type=1) that talks about this vulnerability (content copied to here 5 Jan 2018):

> Description
>
> The Salesforce Security team continuously monitors our systems for any
> evidence of attempts to exploit vulnerabilities to exploits such as
> 'Spectre' and 'Meltdown.'
>
> At this time we have seen no indications of attempts to target
> Salesforce systems using these vulnerabilities.
>
> Resolution
>
> Salesforce response to 'Spectre' and 'Meltdown' Vulnerabilities
>
> - Salesforce is aware of recently reported security vulnerabilities 'Spectre' and "Meltdown,' which are affecting a wide range of computer
>   processors.
> - As is the case for many other companies, Salesforce’s infrastructure uses operating systems that are impacted by these
>   vulnerabilities.
> - Salesforce is working to remediate these vulnerabilities as quickly as possible as the applicable patches are made available by our
>   vendors.
> - Salesforce will continue to monitor the issue and provide updates as appropriate.